# Debugging javascript functions

Tags: javascript, firebug

Is there a way in Firebug (or any other debugger) to see the functions that are being called as a page loads?

Edit: Breakpoint is really not what I'm looking for- I'd like to see the functions being called with the arguments that are being passed as I work on the page - something similar to the console - where I can see Http AJAX Post messages - with post values and the response.

Edit2: It looks like Profiler is something that I was looking for - but is there a way of looking at the parameters passed to the function and the return value?

Comment: Interesting question, this would definitely be helpful. I would set a bounty of 50 rep on this if i were you.

Answer (score 2):

You can always just print it out yourself. ( I know this may not be the answer you wanted.)

But what you can do is add a

```
<div id="debug"></div>
```

in your document.

Then add:

```
function log(str) {
  $('#debug').append(str); // I'm using jQuery here
}
```

and then you can add the logs in your javascript, e.g.:

```
function myFunc(foo, bar, baz) {
  log("myFunc called with ("+foo+", "+bar+", "+baz+")<br/>");

  // your stuff
}
```

Tedious, but effective (IMO).

Answer (score 2):

[Firebug's console.log statement](http://getfirebug.com/console.html) will dump stuff to the console for you, you just need to add console.log statements. For post requests and responses, use the [net panel](http://getfirebug.com/net.html). Personally, I think adding a debug function and div to your page is overkill.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to make this more specific if you want to get more specific answers than "just use a breakpoint".  Do you know what "code profiling" is?  Is that what you want to do?  You can google for "firebug profiler", and there is also some information right here on SO, e.g. [Understanding Firebug profiler output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267618/understanding-firebug-profiler-output)