# Is there any way to see what part of a code is making a webpage slower?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

It is all of the sudden much slower then it was. 
Is there any way I could use some sort of tool that will tell me what part of my code is making my page slow?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Along with Firebug
http://getfirebug.com/

yslow is a great resource to find what is taking long.
http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/

Comment: YSlow is a great tool and should be installed on every web developer's browser

Comment: @Aardvark: Some of us can't due to licensing issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you are brave enough, then have a look at Firebug Profiler output. You can learn a little bit more:

[Understanding Firebug profiler output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267618/understanding-firebug-profiler-output)
http://michaelsync.net/2007/09/10/firebug-tutorial-logging-profiling-and-commandline-part-ii

Answer (score 1):

For IE, [Dynatrace](http://ajax.dynatrace.com) seems quite impressive.

Answer (score 0):

You can view in Firebug which scripts load faster and which slower. If you want to know which is the best way to write your scripts in order for them to perform the best, I don't think there's any tool for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're bound to using IE, there's also a tool called [sIEVE](http://home.orange.nl/jsrosman/) that can help you locate memory leaks in Internet Exploder... I mean Internet Explorer.

It helps you locate bad JS closures and also gives you a readout of what methods/functions are consuming the most threads.  I use this tool in conjunction when testing pages in IE.

Answer (score 0):

It could be hotlinking. Search for it on SO.